# Anonymous or real class definition when using visitor pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

When you use the Visitor pattern and you need to get a variable inside visitor method, how to you proceed ?

I see two approaches. The first one uses anonymous class :

```
// need a wrapper to get the result (which is just a String)
final StringBuild result = new StringBuilder();
final String concat = "Hello ";

myObject.accept(new MyVisitor() {

    @Override
    public void visit(ClassA o)
    {
        // this concatenation is expected here because I've simplified the example
        // normally, the concat var is a complex object (like hashtable) 
        // used to create the result variable 
        // (I know that concatenation using StringBuilder is ugly, but this is an example !)
        result.append(concat + "A");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(ClassB o)
    {
        result.append(concat + "B");
    }
});

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Pros & Cons :

- Pros : you do not need to create a class file for this little behavior
- Cons : I don't like the "final" keyword in this case : the anonymous class is less readable because it calls external variables and you need to use a wrapper to get the requested value (because with the keyword final, you can't reassign the variable)

Another way to do it is to do an external visitor class :

```
public class MyVisitor
{
    private String result;
    private String concat;

    public MyVisitor(String concat)
    {
        this.concat = concat;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(ClassA o)
    {
        result = concat + "A";
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(ClassB o)
    {
        result = concat + "B";
    }

    public String getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }
}

MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor("Hello ");
myObject.accept(visitor);
System.out.println(visitor.getResult());
```

Pros & Cons :

- Pros : all variables are defined in a clean scope, you don't need a wrapper to encapsulate the requested variable
- Cons : need an external file, the getResult() method must be call after the accept method, this is quite ugly because you need to know the function call order to correctly use the visitor

You, what's your approach in this case ? Preferred method ? another idea ?

Comment: These two implementation are only equivalent if you only ever visit one object, otherwise the `result` string would be overwritten every time `visit(ClassA)` or `visit(ClassB)` is called.  Is that intentional?

Comment: yes this is intentional because a visitor pattern is like a method call, it must be call only once time I think

Comment: It'll be called once per object, but AFAIK the point of a visitor pattern is that an operation is called on a collection/tree of objects, once per object.  If you only ever call one object, why would you not just have a method which takes that single object as a parameter?

Comment: As you said, I use object list and not only one object ;) Here is just an example. The real case is quite more complicated !

Comment: Then your visitor object will be called multiple times and only contain the result of the last object.  But (as always), the devil is in the detail, so we'd have to see your accept method.

Comment: the loop looks like : MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor("Hello "); for (MyObject obj : objectList) { obj.accept(visitor); System.out.println(visitor.getResult());}  // as you see, the result is used directly in the loop, so it doesn't matter to override at each loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, both approaches are valid and imo, it really depends on whether you would like to reuse the code or not. By the way, your last 'Con' point is not totally valid since you do not need an 'external file' to declare a class. It might very well be an inner class...

That said, the way I use Visitors is like this:

```
public interface IVisitor<T extends Object> {
    public T visit(ClassA element) throws VisitorException;
    public T visit(ClassB element) throws VisitorException;
}

public interface IVisitable {
    public <T extends Object> T accept(final IVisitor<T> visitor) throws VisitorException;
}

public class MyVisitor implements IVisitor<String> {
    private String concat;

    public MyVisitor(String concat) {
        this.concat = concat;
    }

    public String visit(ClassA classA) throws VisitorException {
        return this.concat + "A";
    }

    public String visit(ClassB classB) throws VisitorException {
        return this.concat + "B";
    }
}

public class ClassA implements IVisitable {
    public <T> T accept(final IVisitor<T> visitor) throws VisitorException {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class ClassB implements IVisitable {
    public <T> T accept(final IVisitor<T> visitor) throws VisitorException {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

// no return value needed?
public class MyOtherVisitor implements IVisitor<Void> {
    public Void visit(ClassA classA) throws VisitorException {
        return null;
    }

    public Void visit(ClassB classB) throws VisitorException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That way, the visited objects are ignorant of what the visitor wants to do with them, yet they do return whatever the visitor wants to return. Your visitor can even 'fail' by throwing an exception.

I wrote the first version of this a few years ago and so far, it has worked for me in every case.

**Disclaimer**: I just hacked this together, quality (or even compilation) not guaranteed. But you get the idea... :)

Comment: spot on ;) that's exactly how I implement the Visitor too.

Comment: excellent ! Clean code. The way you return object from the accept and visit method is really good. Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: The only thing I find strange is that IVisitor just defined a method "visit" with a IVisitable. IVisitor needs one method per IVisitable, isn't it ? If not, how do you write MyVisitor (in your example, it cannot compile because MyVisitor does not override visit(IVisitable)

Comment: You are totally right, of course. I adjusted the code to reflect your comments. That's what you get when you do not test your code... :(

Answer (score 1):

I do not see an `interface` being implemented in your second example, but I believe it is there.  I would add to your interface (or make a sub interface) that has a `getResult()` method on it.

That would help both example 1 and 2.  You would not need a wrapper in 1, because you can define the `getResult()` method to return the result you want.  In example 2, because `getResult()` is a part of your interface, there is no function that you 'need to know'.

My preference would be to create a new class, unless each variation of the class is only going to be used once.  In which case I would inline it anonymously.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I use interface but I've don't write here it to be concise. in your example, you define the getResult in the interface, but it  does not change anything : you need to call the accept() method before calling getResult

Comment: I suggested adding the `getResult()` method to the interface so that it is a known method.  You said that it was a con in example 2 because you have to 'know the method to call'.

Comment: yes I understand what you are saying, but what I was saying is you need to know the call order, not the method name. You need to know that you must call accept() and only after that you can call getResult()

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of a *cleaner* design, the second approach is preferrable for the same exact reasons you've already stated.

In a normal TDD cycle I would start off with an anonymous class and refactored it out a bit later. However, if the visitor would only be needed in that one place and its complexity would match that of what you've provided in the example (i.e. *not complex*), I would have left it hanging and refactor to a separate class later *if needed* (e.g. another use case appeared, complexity of the visitor/surrounding class increased).

Comment: Agree with the refactoring approach of the TDD method

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the second approach. Having the visitor in its full fledged class also serves the purpose of documentation and clean code. I do not agree with the cons that you have mentioned with the approach. Say you have an arraylist, and you don't add any element to it and do a get, surely you will get a null but that doesn't mean that it is necessarily wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One of the points of the visitor pattern is to allow for multiple visitor types.  If you create an anonymous class, you are kind of breaking the pattern.

You should change your `accept` method to be

```
public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
   visitor.visit(this);
}
```

Since you pass `this` into the visitor, `this` being the object that is visited, the visitor can access the object's property according to the standard access rules.

Comment: I know that, but I've do not write the MyObject class because I was thinking it was not helpful in this example. Of I've got an interface and several accept methods. But using anonymous class does not break the pattern.

Comment: Or I misunderstand why it breaks it ;)